# Float div on right inside of another div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with class properties `display: block; width: 100%;`. I can not change this.

I am trying to float a smaller div inside of it on the right hand side, however, it always appears below the parent div. How do I have to markup the css?

```
.parent_div {
display: block;
width: 100%;
} 

.child_div {
 height: 51px;
 width: 51px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;

 }

<div class="parent_div"><div class="child_div">on right</div></div>
```

Comment: Is this a bogus question? The reason I ask is because you have a reputation over 1400 and the questions you have provided excellent, accepted answers to on this site have dealt with subject matter MUCH MORE complex than your question here. Users with SINGLE DIGIT REPUTATIONS are providing answers. You're testing something about the users of this site or the SO site itself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
.child_div {
 height: 51px;
 width: 51px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
float:right;
 }
```

here is [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kFfmM/)

Comment: The reason is that parent content does not has any content and as height is specified on div, child div looks the below the parent div.

Comment: No, the reason is that the child is floated.

Comment: I have updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CsYhL/3/. See if this solves your purpose

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
.parent_div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
.child_div {
    height: 51px;
    width: 51px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rF8vc/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
    .parent_div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    } 

   .child_div {
   height: 51px;
   width: 51px;
   overflow: hidden;
   float:right;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

delete your position absolute and add float:right;

```
.child_div {
 height: 51px;
 width: 51px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a position absolute in your child div so you can use right:0

```
.child_div {
height: 51px;
width: 51px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;

right:0px;
}
```

or you can delete your position and add a float:right

```
.child_div {
height: 51px;
width: 51px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;

float:right;
}
```