# How to prevent floating nested divs from moving content down

Tags: html, css

I've got a nested div,  based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972831/float-div-on-right-inside-of-another-div/24972981).

The output of a *wysiwyg* editor are displayed using nested divs (so I can't just resize every element). The problem is elements like tables and youtube's iframe videos are pushed down, instead of resizing.

```
.parent-floating-div {
  display: block; 
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.child-floating-div { 
 overflow: auto ;
 float:right;
}
```

How can I prevent elements like the html table from moving down?

[image: my site]

Comment: You could try using `display: inline-block`

Comment: The page stays the same :(

Comment: Put all the rest of the children beside the side bar in a single div and put it before `.child-floating-div`. You might also need to give it `float: left` (I don't really remember. I didn't use `float` for a LONG time). Consider using more modern css features such as `flex` and `grid`.